# how do I make this scroll only shift the container div instead of the entire body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making an HTML5 iOS app using a UIWebView and I am trying to make it so that when a user navigates tabs there is a horizontal slide / scroll effect from tab to tab.  The slide / scroll effect is working but it is shifting the entire document instead of just the container div.  What I want is for just the elements in the container div to scroll / slide and the footer to stay in place.

```
<body> 
    <div id="container"> 
        <div id="home-content">
            <div></div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="gallery-content">
        </div>
        <div id="merch-content">
        </div>
        <div id="apps-content">
        </div>
        <div id="press-content">
        </div>
        <div id="footer"> 
            <ul class="nav"> 
                <li class="home active"><span><a href="#home-content" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span></li> 
                <li class="gallery"><span><a href="#gallery-content" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span></li> 
                <li class="merch"><span><a href="#merch-content" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span></li> 
                <li class="apps"><span><a href="#apps-content" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span></li> 
                <li class="press"><span><a href="#press-content" style="text-decoration:none;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></span></li> 
            </ul> 
        </div>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {
          $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
            var $anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
          }, 1000);
          event.preventDefault();
          });
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

Comment: Most likely because you are calling scrollLeft on the elements html and body, which is pretty much the deliberate way to move the whole document. You should put all the tabs excluding footer into a further container and then scroll that using $('#tabContainer').stop().animate(.....

Answer (score 0):

Your `div#footer` is inside your `div#container`.

Move it outside the `div#container` and then change your script to

```
$('#container').stop().animate({
    scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That was my first thought too but when i tried it it broke the scroll.  Does not throw error it just dosent scroll.